# How to reproject a rendered image onto a plane intersecting camera's view?

Tags: camera, texture-painting, coordinates

I am trying to mimick the process of mapping an 2D image onto a 3D surface (or "orthorectifying" for aerial/satellite image).

The set-up is the following:

1. a ground plane (in green in the figure below)
2. an object (a red cube in the figure below)
3. a camera (which frustrum has been scaled below)

I believe the simplest way is to map the rendered image to the yellow extent, that correspond to the intersection of the frustrum with the "ground" plane.

Any insight on how to achieve that, via the GUI commands or using `bpy` ? My guess is:

1. find the four coordinate of the intersection
2. warp the image externally or using UV mapping onto a new plane + "flat" rendering or texture export

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into the BLAM addon yet? I am not sure about what you have set up, but BLAM helps to get geo organized for matching to a camera.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out @CraigDJones, the plug-in it's definitively worth a read.